# Does openwrt have a dhcp client?

Tags: dhcp, openwrt, dhclient

I was surprised that building a default open wrt config created an image without dhclient, After some digging we found odhcpd package for use as the dhcp server but I still can't find any package that corresponds to dhclient.

Is there an alternative I am supposed to know about or do I need to go outside of menuconfig to get the packages I need?

Comment: I believe dnsmasq is used for that

Comment: Isn't dnsmasq a dhcp server not a client?

Answer (score 4):

The command is named udhcpc and its part of busybox in openwrt.